# How can I not update records using this Upsert?

Tags: trigger, upsert

I am attempting to create a new child record for each value of the multi-value field. I can only get the following code to create a new child record for the first entry into the list :

```
//Data fields and objects :

//Policy_Profile__c - the parent object which is kicking off this trigger

//Product_Affected_Entry__c - child object which will be used for new records

//Product_Affected3__c - field in parent object populated with selected options

//Vendor_Product__c - object loooked up and containing the profile(recordid) of the entry Named in the newly created child record
//***SHOULD HAVE BEEN NAMED VENDOR_PRODUCT_PROFILE__C in this case because it now has the same name as the child record field which
//contains the record id 

//Policy__c - lookup field on newly created child record which will be used to contain the Parent record's ID

//Vendor__c - lookup field on newly created child record which is pulling another lookup field from the parent object 
//which contains the id to the PARENT of the entry Named in the newly created child record - ie the object queried 
//in the VF controller to produce the multi-select choices - in this case the parent of the Vendor_Product__c object

//Vendor_Product__c - lookup field on the newly created child record which contains the recordid of the entry Named in the newly created record
//ie it is the field in the new child record which is populated by the result of the query in this trigger
//it is the recordid of one of the selections which appear in the names list of this trigger
//****CAUTION**** - in this case it has the same name as the object looked up

//Policy_and_Product__c - text field in the newly created child object which contains a combination of the name 
//of the selection which appears in the names list as well as well as the recordid retrieved in the query - in 
//this case it is the recordid plugged into the Vendor_Product__c field of the newly created child record
//****VERY IMPORTANT***** - THIS MUST BE AN EXTERNAL ID FIELD BECAUSE IT IS REFERENCED BY THE UPSERT TO PREVENT 
//DUPLICATE CHILD RECORDS FROM BEING CREATED IF A SELECTION IS MADE MULTIPLE TIMES BY THE USER

trigger AutoCreateSubsServOnContrOv on Policy_Profile__c(After insert, after update) 
{
    List<Product_Affected_Entry__c> subs = new List<Product_Affected_Entry__c>();

    List<String> subAccNames=new List<String>();

    for(Policy_Profile__c newCont: Trigger.New) 
    {
        if(newCont.Products_Affected3__c!='[]') 
        {
            // split out the multi-select picklist using a comma delimiter
            System.debug('Products_Affected3__c ' + newCont.Products_Affected3__c);

            String temp = newCont.Products_Affected3__c;
            temp.normalizeSpace();
            temp = temp.replace(']','');
            temp = temp.replace('[','');
            String[] all = temp.split(',');
            subAccNames.addAll(all);
            System.debug('************************temp'+temp);

            for(String acctName : all)
            {
                subAccNames.add(acctName.normalizeSpace());
                System.debug('subAccNames !!! ' + subAccNames); 
            }
        }
    }


    Map<String, Vendor_Product__c> subAccIdsByName=new Map<String, Vendor_Product__c>();
    System.debug('FIRSTsubAccIdsByName='+subAccIdsByName);   

    for (Vendor_Product__c subacc : [select id, Vendor__c, Name from Vendor_Product__c where Name in :subAccNames]) 
    {

        subAccIdsByName.put(subacc.Name, subacc);
        System.debug('subAcc Name and ID=' + subacc.Name +'Id=' + subacc.id + 'Vendor_c=' + subacc.Vendor__c);
    }

    System.debug('SECONDsubAccIdsByName=' + subAccIdsByName);

    //For each position processed by the trigger, add a new  
    //Product_Affected_Entry__c record for the specified Products_Affected3__c.  
    //Note that Trigger.New is a list of all the new positions  
    //that are being created.  

    for (Policy_Profile__c newContract : Trigger.New) 
    {
        if (newContract.Products_Affected3__c != '[]') 
        {
            // split out the multi-select picklist using a comma delimiter
            System.debug('Products_Affected3__c ' + newContract.Products_Affected3__c);

            String temp = newContract.Products_Affected3__c;


            temp.normalizeSpace();
            temp = temp.replace(']','');
            temp = temp.replace('[','');
            String[] all = temp.split(',');

            for(String productsonpolicy: all)
            {

                for(Integer i=0; i<subAccIdsByName.keySet().size(); i++)
                {

                    if(productsonpolicy==(new List<String>(subAccIdsByName.keySet()))[i])
                    {
                        Product_Affected_Entry__c ssoc = new Product_Affected_Entry__c(
                            Policy__c = newContract.Id,

                            Vendor_Product__c = subAccIdsByName.values()[i].Id, 

                            Vendor__c = subAccIdsByName.values()[i].Vendor__c,

                            Policy_and_Product__c = newContract.Name + '~' + (new List<String>(subAccIdsByName.keySet()))[i]
                        );
                        subs.add(ssoc);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    upsert subs Policy_and_Product__c;
}
```

Any kind of help I can get I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You don't include your entire trigger, so difficult to answer beyond saying that you can query all of the records related to the parent record Ids, then filter out all the child records that already exist so you don't try to insert them again.

Comment: crmprogdev - thank you for your input. I have updated my original post and included the entire trigger. Yes, I would like to somehow filter all existing records which have a matching Policy_and_Product__c field out and not update them. But I don't know how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got it in your code that the `Policy_Product__c` field is used to prevent dupes with upsert.

Collect all of those values and run a query on `Product_Affected_Entry__c`. If any of them are returned, remove matching new `Product_Affected_Entry__c's` from your list named `subs`. To make that easier, create a map with those values against something else that's unique if you can since your list has no Ids.

You already have the map `subAccIdsByName` which might allow you to run a query ahead of time using either `.values()` or `.keyset()`. Since I don't know the relationships and fields in your object schema, I can't say one way or another.

**Edit**

Look for comments encapsulated with '***' in the revised code below.

```
                    map<string,Product_Affected_Entry__c>PolPrd2PAE = new map<string,Product_Affected_Entry__c>();
                    // ***declare the above map outside of a for loop*** 

                    for(String productsonpolicy: all)    
                     {   
                        productsonpolicy = productsonpolicy.normalizeSpace();

                        Product_Affected_Entry__c ssoc = new Product_Affected_Entry__c(
                        Policy__c = newContract.Id,
                        VendorNewRecord__c = newContract.Vendor__c,
                        Vendor_Product__c = subAccIdsByName.get(productsonpolicy), 

                        //Policy_Poroduct__c field is used as key to prevent duplicates with the Upsert
                        Policy_and_Product__c = newContract.Name + '~' + subAccIdsByName.get(productsonpolicy)
                        );

                        //***Add ea new Policy_and_Product__c as the key to a map with*** 
                        //***ea new Product_Affected_Entry__c record as the value***
                        PolPrd2PAE.put(Policy_and_Product__c, ssoc);

                        subs.add(ssoc);
                     }
```

With the above revisions, you can now you can write a query using `WHERE Policy_and_Product__c IN :PolPrd2PAE.keyset()` to get a list of any previously inserted records related to the Parent Record Ids in Trigger.new. I'm confident that you can get the Parent Ids easily enough yourself and add them to the WHERE condition if they're needed to write the rest of the query.

Once you do that, here's how to find the matches and remove them from `subs`:

```
list<Product_Affected_Entry__c>QueryResults = [SELECT Id, Policy_and_Product__c, etc FROM Product_Affected_Entry__c WHERE .... ];
for(Product_Affected_Entry__c QR : QueryResults)
{
    for(Product_Affected_Entry__c s : subs)
    {

        if(QR.Policy_and_Product__c = s.Policy_and_Product__c){
            subs.rem(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: crmprogdev- thank you very much. I understand in theory what you're saying. I just can't write the code. The relationship btwn the main Product_Profile__c object and the object used for the new Product_Affected_Entry__c is ProductAffected__r. But I'm not sure why you need that. I would love it if you could show that necessary code to me - although I understand if that's asking too much. Thanks again.

Comment: See my edited answer which has example code of how to sort for duplicate records and how to get what you should need to write your query.

Comment: After thinking this over I realized I could accomplish this by populating the VendorNew__c field of the newly created record with the Vendor__c field of the queried record which is also populating the Vendor_Product__c. I've put Vendor__c in the query, but I can't figure out how to also refer to it at the end. Can you tell me how to do that please ? I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you're suggesting because if I'm not mistaken, you have a many to one relationship with the parent. You could use it to get other related records in advance to sort on, but not for any other purpose.

Comment: The map needed to refer to an entire object in order to pull additional fields from it. Map<String, Vendor_Product__c>  instead of Map<String, id>. Several other changes were made as well. Now that that's in there it is properly pulling the other field from the queried record. However, now it's only creating a new child record for the first entry of the list. I updated my original post to now show the current code.

Comment: Unless you've included all of your code, I suggest you create a new post stating your existing problem. It seems as though this post has morphing into much more than the initial question. You now have the pattern you need to do the job. I suggest you add lots of debug statements to figure out where your problem is. I don't see anything in your code above to tell me what you've done. It seems as though its now become a new question that you can reference as related to this one.

Comment: crmprogdev - you're right. I was thinking that when I was editing the post. It's really changed too much. I apologize for the confusion. Thank you very much for all of your help. I really appreciate it.